# how to check if element exist in document field type array ? flutter

Tags: arrays, list, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have a collection of questions which contain an array of strings of id of user liked this questions

i want to check if an id exist in this array then show a widget

```
List result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('QuestionBank')
        .doc(questionID)
        .snapshots()
        .map((event) => {List.from(event['userLiked'])})
        .toList();
    return result.contains(uid);
  }
```

this is how i add item in array

```
Future<void> updateQuestionLikes(String uids, String userUid) async {
    await questionBank.doc(uids).set({
      'likes': FieldValue.increment(1),
      'userLiked': FieldValue.arrayUnion([userUid])
    }, SetOptions(merge: true));
  }
```

i wan to check if a uid exist in userLiked field in the firestore
does not work
any ideas or solutions can help ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's that:

```
  Future<bool> ifUidExist(String uid)async {
    final query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("QuestionBank")
        .where("userLiked", arrayContains: uid)
        .get();

    return query.docs.isNotEmpty;
  }
```

Comment: Question bank collection contains alot of questions ane every question contain its own userliked array field i want to know if true or false for specific question in the collection

Comment: But a query it's only on a collection.(You can check also if the document exist). If you know the path of the document, you need to download all the document and check what you want like you've done "return result.contains(uid);"